# ReactJS - Loading undesirable repeated data from the API

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching Data from a Dribbble API. It is almost succefully but it is loading 12 shots from the API, and after this it is occurring a problem by repeating the same 12 again and then it after this it is loading the others in a right way: 13,14,15...

The shots' return:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12. 
OK RIGHT
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12. 
repetition problem!!! WRONG
13,14,15,16... OK RIGHT

What is the solution for this undesirable repetition?

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Waypoint from 'react-waypoint';
import Dribbble from './Dribbble';  

export default class Dribbbles extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { page: 1, shots: [] };    
        this.getShots = this.getShots.bind(this);
    }    

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getShots();
    }

    getShots() {
        return $.getJSON('https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots?page='+ this.state.page + '&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE&callback=?')
        .then((resp) => {
            var newShots = this.state.shots.concat(resp.data);       
            this.setState({        
                page: this.state.page + 1,
                shots: newShots
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const shots = this.state.shots.map((val, i) => {
            return <Dribbble dados={val} key={i} />
        });

        return (
        <div>
        <ul>{shots}</ul>
        <Waypoint
        onEnter={this.getShots}
        />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind logging state on getShots method and tell what exactly is getting logged everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why

I think the onEnter event from your `Waypoint` component is triggered unexpectedly, which has caused the getShots() function being called multiple times.

#### How

My suggestion is to specify a `dataFecthed` state to control whether the Waypoint component mount or not.Just like below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Waypoint from 'react-waypoint'
import Dribbble from './Dribbble'

export default class Dribbbles extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { page: 1, shots: [], dataFetched: true }
    this.getShots = this.getShots.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getShots()
  }

  getShots() {
    this.setState({
      dataFetched: false,
    })
    return $.getJSON(
      'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots?page=' +
        this.state.page +
        '&access_token=41ff524ebca5e8d0bf5d6f9f2c611c1b0d224a1975ce37579326872c1e7900b4&callback=?'
    ).then(resp => {
      var newShots = this.state.shots.concat(resp.data)
      this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        shots: newShots,
        dataFetched: true,
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const shots = this.state.shots.map((val, i) => {
      return <Dribbble dados={val} key={i} />
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{shots}</ul>
        {this.state.dataFetched && <Waypoint onEnter={this.getShots} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```